# How to handle violating primary key constraints in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database

I have a login page, users have ID's and ID is the primary key in the table. I also have an admin account, and admin can create users. But when i create a user account with an existing ID, the web page crashes. I want to handle this situation and give a warning indicating that this ID exists and cannot be created. Here is my code:

```
  public void CreateStudent(int ID, String status, String email, String firstName, String lastName, String password, String level, String program)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());


    string query1 = "insert into StudentTable(Name,Surname,ID,email,level,program,status,password,Type) values(@firstName,@lastName,@ID,@email,@level,@program,@status,@password,'Student')";


    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query1,con);

    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@level", level);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@program", program);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);

    int result;
    con.Open();
    result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();


}
```

Can anyone help me with this? Thanls

Comment: Not a direct answer, but please, please, please learn and **use** paramterized queries, **especially** since you're developing a web application.  Your code as is is wide-open to SQL Injection.

Comment: For a more direct answer to your question, I would used a Stored Procedure to do the insert.  The SP would check for an existing ID and if it finds one return something indicating that ID already exists, otherwise it would complete the insert.

Comment: @Tim i have heard the same thing many times, can you please write the same query as parametrized query so that i can understand how to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made the e-mail attribute as a primary key and then checked the database whether same e-mail exists and that worked

Comment: What does this have to do with original question? Modifying a primary key in this way is a BIG DEAL. I don't understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways.  You could catch an Exception and display an error message.  That will also help in other error scenario's, like a lost connection.

However, if it's a situation you expect to occur during normal operation, you should handle the situation without an Exception.  One way to do that is to have your `insert` only insert a row with a new `id`:

```
insert  YourTable
        (id, col1, col2, ...)
select  @id
,       @col1
,       @col2
,       ...
where   not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable
        where   id = @id
        )
```

Pass parameters to your query like:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", 42);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col1", "value1");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col2", "value2");
```

Now `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns the number of affected rows.  You can use that to check if the `insert` actually added a new row to the table:

```
var result = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (result == 1)
{
    lblResult.Text = "New row inserted!";
    lblResult.Color = Color.Green;
}
else
{
    lblResult.Text = "Failed to insert new row.";
    lblResult.Color = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but i am new to asp.net and do not know how to use parametrized queries so i have a question about your answer:is the insert ... where not exists ... statement a string variable?

Comment: Yes, you'd store that query as a string in `command.CommandText`.  The `@varname` are parameters that will, among other things, protect you from SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

Rather than tying to handle the error that comes back from attempting to add a user with the same ID, it would be better to check for the user's existence first and only create the new account if you can. Though you still need to handle the exception to cater for the case where two people try to create the same record.

So you'd have the following SQL:

```
select * from StudentTable where ID = @newID
```

and if this found a record you could report the error. If it doesn't find anything then you can go ahead and create the new record.

Though if you are using the ID as the primary key it would be better to have that as an [Identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx) column on the table and have it auto-increment when you create a new row. You'd still have to check to see if the student already exists - use the e-mail as the human readable uniqueness condition.

If you add uniqueness constraint on the e-mail column then you'll be able to trap the case of two people trying to create the same record.

Comment: This ignores concurrency. Another user could create the same ID after the select, but before insert. The insertion exception should be handled in any case, even if the select is done for better user experience.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - indeed it does.